# Login auth with 2 different tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I have the laravel 8 auth login form working perfectly, but i need to create a new athentication system for a different kind of users that are being stored in the database in another table with their own username and password. how can i achieve that?

Comment: I think this will help you - https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel

Comment: i'm stuck in the part that says "Open the LoginController in app/Http/Controllers/Auth and edit as follows:". Because there is no loginController file in a new installation of laravel 8 breeze. where can i find that file?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users - Here in the documentation it shows how to create your own LoginController

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using Guard by adding a new guard in "config/auth.php".

```
'guards' => [
     'web' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'users',
      ],

      'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'admin_users',
      ],
 ],

 'providers' => [
      'users' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Models\User::class,
      ],

      'admin_users' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Models\Admin\AdminUser::class,
      ],
  ],
```

Here I have created a new Auth Guard "admin". Using this guard you can attempt login from a different table.

For login attempts:
For User:

```
if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => 
    $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
 }
```

For Admin:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => 
   $request->password], $request->remember)) {
   return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
}
```